# Is there a way to transform the following integral equation into a differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, integral-equations, integral-transforms

The resolution of an elasticity exercise has lead to the following integral equation
$$
\int_r^R \frac{F_1(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}} + 
\int_0^r \frac{F_2(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} = 0 \quad\quad (0<r<R) \, ,
$$
where $R>0$.
I was wondering whether a relation between $F_1$ and $F_2$ could be established.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify one integral at the expense of making the other one more complicated, but I am not sure whether this is waht you want. Multiplying both sides with $r/\sqrt{s^2-r^2}$ and integrating $r$ from $0$ to $s$, 
$$
\int_0^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}\int_r^R \frac{F_1(t)dt}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}}
+\int_0^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}\int_0^r \frac{F_2(t)dt}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}}=0.
$$
Changing the order of integration in the second expression, 
$$
\int_0^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}\int_0^r \frac{F_2(t)dt}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} = 
\int_0^s F_2(t)dt\int_{t}^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}}.
$$
The inner integration is exactly $\pi/2$, and we get
$$
\int_0^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}\int_r^R \frac{F_1(t)dt}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}} + \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^s F_2(t)dt=0.
$$
Taking derivative on both sides,
$$
F_2(s) = -\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s \frac{rdr}{(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}}\int_r^R \frac{F_1(t)dt}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}}. 
$$
Similarly, we can express $F_1$ in terms of $F_2$, by multiplying both sides with $r/\sqrt{s^2-r^2}$ and integrating $r$ from $s$ to $R$

Comment: Very much thanks for your powerful answer. I think this expression will be sufficient for further analysis.

Comment: @RobertoFermi You can find more references by searching "Abel Integral Equations"

Comment: Thanks. I am searching for that. I was wondering if you could provide some hits for a very related question <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955136/how-to-solve-analytically-an-integral-equation-involving-two-terms-with-differen>

Comment: @RobertoFermi Can you double check the first term is $\int_r^R\frac{\phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^2-r^2}} $ or $\int_r^R\frac{t\phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^2-r^2}} $? The latter seems easier that the former.

Comment: I have double-checked. It is in fact $\int_r^R \frac{\phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^2-r^2}}$ i.e. as written in the question.

Comment: Just an aside note $\phi(0)=0$. Your prescribed method seems to works out nicely and leads to a more amenable integral equation.. Thanks